# JavaScript Regex checkbox

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a problem with this regex

```
(?=.*' + $(this).val() + ')
```

I have a table with rows e.g

```
Plane, Air
Plane, Air Port
```

So when I check checkbox "Air" and "Plane" my regex will be:

```
(?=.*Plane)(?=.*Air)
```

it will show me all rows, but I want to show just first. Is there any solution to match whole words with Positive lookahead?

Comment: remove `g` modifier.

Comment: regex doesn't seem to be the right tool here. This is just plain-text search, a simple ES6 `string.includes(searchedString)` would be better

Comment: @Aaron I need to use regex. This is datatables function oTable.fnFilter(search, index, true, false); and my search parameter when I check these checkboxes is string - (?=.*Plane)(?=.*Air)

Comment: @AvinashRaj I didn't quite understand, but I think I don't have g modifier in my regex.

Comment: Please provide a fiddle to see it in action. However, it seems like a missing API feature, please check the documentation and bug/feature request repository related to what your are using.

Comment: Any news on this? Did you solve the problem?